# Perfect way to remove specific border in html

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table with `border-collapse` applied. I want to remove some `td` border such as `border-right` within the table. I used the following css to do the job but this code also remove 1px of the other borders I don't want to remove. In fact it adds `1px solid white` to the top and bottom border of the table where the removed `border-right` was there

```css
.no-border-right {
      border-right: solid 10px #FFF!important;
    }

   table {
       border-collapse: collapse;
       font-size: 16px;
       padding: 6px;
    }
    table td {
       border: 10px solid gray;       
    }
    table th {
       border: 10px solid gray;      
    }
```

```html
<table align="center">
  <tr>
      <th>sl</th>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>score</th>
      <th>rank</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td class="no-border-right">James</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

```
<table>
   <tr>
       <th></th>
       <th></th>
       <th></th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td></td>
       <td class="no-border-right"></td>
       <td></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

How can I remove without affecting the other borders?

[image: Output table]

My expected result from the snippet is below:

[image: Expected output]

Comment: Would need to see the rest of the code ( html / CSS ) or a rendered copy of the page.

Comment: @Pytth, please see the updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
table {
   border-collapse: collapse;
   padding: 6px;
}
table td, table th {
   border: 1px solid gray;  
}
table td.no-border-right {
  border-right: none!important;
}
table td.no-border-right + td {
  border-left: none!important;
}
```

```html
<table align="center">
  <tr>
      <th>sl</th>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>score</th>
      <th>rank</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td class="no-border-right">James</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I can still see the white 1px spot.

Comment: This removes all the borders inside the table. I want specific border. Please look at the updated question.

Comment: does not work well with border-bottom. But it deserves accepted as it gives me info and answer my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `border-right: none;` that should do it for you, also I left you a code snippet down there if you get stuck.

```css
.no-border-right {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
  /* from here up is not it's necessary just to help visually see it demonstration */
  
  border-right: none; /* Use this to remove right border */
}
```

```html
<div class="no-border-right">
  <p>Hello Wolrd!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Please try with my snippet. I also updated my question

Comment: This does not work. I am working on html table, not div

Comment: Oops sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Make the right-border color's alpha 0 like so:

```
border-right { 10px solid rgba(0,0,0,0); }
```

```css
.no-border-right {
      border-right: 10px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
    }

   table {
       border-collapse: collapse;
       font-size: 16px;
       padding: 6px;
    }
    table td {
       border: 10px solid gray;       
    }
    table th {
       border: 10px solid gray;      
    }
```

```html
<table align="center">
  <tr>
      <th>sl</th>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>score</th>
      <th>rank</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td class="no-border-right">James</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but as you can see from the output of your snippet, the white color is still there right above James

Comment: Not on my screen.  What browser are you using? Im on latest Chrome.

Comment: I am using firefox latest